# Gerar multiplos gráficos em um loop usando x11() e dois indices diferentes no R

Tags: r

Pessoal essa é a minha lista.

```
mylist=list(list(a = c(2, 3, 4, 5), b = c(3, 4, 5, 5), c = c(3, 7, 5, 
5), d = c(3, 4, 9, 5), e = c(3, 4, 5, 9), f = c(3, 4, 1, 9), 
    g = c(3, 1, 5, 9), h = c(3, 3, 5, 9), i = c(3, 17, 3, 9), 
    j = c(3, 17, 3, 9)), list(a = c(2, 5, 48, 4), b = c(7, 4, 
5, 5), c = c(3, 7, 35, 5), d = c(3, 843, 9, 5), e = c(3, 43, 
5, 9), f = c(3, 4, 31, 39), g = c(3, 1, 5, 9), h = c(3, 3, 5, 
9), i = c(3, 17, 3, 9), j = c(3, 17, 3, 9)), list(a = c(2, 3, 
4, 35), b = c(3, 34, 5, 5), c = c(3, 37, 5, 5), d = c(38, 4, 
39, 5), e = c(3, 34, 5, 9), f = c(33, 4, 1, 9), g = c(3, 1, 5, 
9), h = c(3, 3, 35, 9), i = c(3, 17, 33, 9), j = c(3, 137, 3, 
9)), list(a = c(23, 3, 4, 85), b = c(3, 4, 53, 5), c = c(3, 7, 
5, 5), d = c(3, 4, 9, 5), e = c(3, 4, 5, 9), f = c(3, 34, 1, 
9), g = c(38, 1, 5, 9), h = c(3, 3, 5, 9), i = c(3, 137, 3, 9
), j = c(3, 17, 3, 9)), list(a = c(2, 3, 48, 5), b = c(3, 4, 
5, 53), c = c(3, 73, 53, 5), d = c(3, 43, 9, 5), e = c(33, 4, 
5, 9), f = c(33, 4, 13, 9), g = c(3, 81, 5, 9), h = c(3, 3, 5, 
9), i = c(3, 137, 3, 9), j = c(3, 173, 3, 9)))
```

A cada comando `x11()` eu pretendo preencher com 5 gráficos atela aberta. Como `j=1:10` eu vou precisar chamar `x11()` 10 vezes.

E é aí que eu estou me embolando todo.

A unica forma que eu consegui gerar os 10 gráficos foi alterando o valor do `j` de 1 até 10.

Ou seja:

O primeiro gráfico é esse:

```
x11()
par(mfrow=c(3,2))

for (i in 1:5) {      
  #for (j in 1:10){   
    plot.ts(mylist[[i]][[1]])
  #}

}
```

O segundo gráfico é esse:

```
x11()
par(mfrow=c(3,2))

for (i in 1:5) { 
  #for (j in 1:10){
    plot.ts(mylist[[i]][[2]])
  #}
}
```

Até j=10. Portanto 10 gráficos, com cada um contendo 5 gráficos.

Repare que eu tenho q gerar um por um, "na mão". Substituindo o valor do j de 1 até 10.

Como faço para automatizar isso certinho? Onde coloco os comandos `x11() ; par(mfrow=c(3,2))`?

Answer (score 2):

Só colocar o loop `for` com o `j` antes do `x11()`:

```
    for(j in 1:10) {

      x11()
      par(mfrow=c(3,2))

      for (i in 1:5) { 
          plot.ts(mylist[[i]][[j]])
      }
    }
```

Comment: Valeu demais. estava com dificuldade de entender a prioridade no for. Quando j for igual a 1 a "prioridade" para acabar os indices passa a ser do i né? Ou seja, quando j=1 i passa por todos os seus valores de um até 5. Depois de i=5, j=2 aí começa tudo de novo, i=1 até 10, e assim por diante né? @Marcus Nunes

Comment: Isso mesmo! Depende da ordem dos `for`, onde o primeiro `for` será o último a terminar.

Answer (score 1):

Cada `x11()` é uma nova janela gráfica. Portanto, basta abrir uma nova janela sempre que os gráficos anteriores forem todos plotados.

O mesmo vale para `par(mfrow=c(3,2))`. Este comando serve apenas para definir a configuração interna dos gráficos dentro de cada `x11`. Portanto, faz mais sentido definir esta configuração logo após a criação da janela gráfica.

```
for (j in 1:10) { 

  x11()
  par(mfrow=c(3,2))

  for (i in 1:5){
    plot.ts(mylist[[i]][[j]])
  }
}
```

Não vou colocar todos os gráficos aqui, mas veja que meu computador conseguiu gerar todas as 10 janelas desejadas, indexadas de 4 a 13.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]